# Recording data Vuejs for different routes

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm working in vue file and i have the following code

```
 <router-link :to ="{name: 'detailed'}" tag = 'li' @click = 'getData("test")'> testing</router-link>
```

and in script its ->

```
export default {
data(){
    return{
        choice: ''
    }

},

methods: {
    getData(asd){
        this.choice = asd
        console.log(this.choice)
    }
}
```

}

so basically what i need is to pass data from getData to another route. As you can see when i press it, the router-link will take me to another page and on that new page i need to use the data that was created when that link was pressed.

Comment: Where's Java involved?

Comment: fixed it, but anyway do u have any ideas how to solve the problem above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your method to trigger on click you need to add the `.native` modifier i.e.

```
@click.native="getData('test')"
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Hope this helps!